# ListSliceContourPlot3D plots Blanks with List1 and plots perfectly with List2. List1 == List2. Mathematica Version 10.4

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'm trying to do ContourPlots using the Function ListContourPlot3d. I have generated List1 and List2 using the following code. Here is the preliminary code to generate List1 and List2.

```
ks = 0.77459666924148337704; 
z = 0;
xis = Partition[{-ks, -ks, -ks, z, -ks, -ks, ks, -ks, -ks, -ks, 
   z, -ks, z, z, -ks, ks, z, -ks, -ks, ks, -ks, z, ks, -ks, ks, 
   ks, -ks, -ks, -ks, z, z, -ks, z, ks, -ks, z, -ks, z, z, z, z, z, 
   ks, z, z, -ks, ks, z, z, ks, z, ks, ks, z, -ks, -ks, ks, z, -ks, 
   ks, ks, -ks, ks, -ks, z, ks, z, z, ks, ks, z, ks, -ks, ks, ks, z, 
   ks, ks, ks, ks, ks}, 
  3];   


enodes = {2, 21, 22, 3, 6, 23, 24, 7, 25, 26, 27, 10, 28, 29, 30, 14, 
   18, 31, 32, 19};

gloCoordsEl = {{2.5, 0., 0.}, {5., 0., 0.}, {5., 1., 0.}, {2.5, 1., 
    0.}, {2.5, 0., 1.}, {5., 0., 1.}, {5., 1., 1.}, {2.5, 1., 
    1.}, {3.75, 0., 0.}, {5., 0.5, 0.}, {3.75, 1., 0.}, {2.5, 0.5, 
    0.}, {3.75, 0., 1.}, {5., 0.5, 1.}, {3.75, 1., 1.}, {2.5, 0.5, 
    1.}, {2.5, 0., 0.5}, {5., 0., 0.5}, {5., 1., 0.5}, {2.5, 1., 0.5}};

NshapeList = {-(1/8)*(1 - g)*(1 - h)*(1 - r)*(2 + g + h + 
      r), -(1/8)*(1 + g)*(1 - h)*(1 - r)*(2 - g + h + r), -(1/8)*(1 + 
      g)*(1 + h)*(1 - r)*(2 - g - h + r), -(1/8)*(1 - g)*(1 + h)*(1 - 
      r)*(2 + g - h + r), -(1/8)*(1 - g)*(1 - h)*(1 + r)*(2 + g + h - 
      r), -(1/8)*(1 + g)*(1 - h)*(1 + r)*(2 - g + h - r), -(1/8)*(1 + 
      g)*(1 + h)*(1 + r)*(2 - g - h - r), -(1/8)*(1 - g)*(1 + h)*(1 + 
      r)*(2 + g - h - r), (1/4)*(1 - g)*(1 + g)*(1 - h)*(1 - r), (1/
      4)*(1 - h)*(1 + h)*(1 + g)*(1 - r), (1/4)*(1 - g)*(1 + g)*(1 + 
      h)*(1 - r), (1/4)*(1 - h)*(1 + h)*(1 - g)*(1 - r), (1/4)*(1 - 
      g)*(1 + g)*(1 - h)*(1 + r), (1/4)*(1 - h)*(1 + h)*(1 + g)*(1 + 
      r), (1/4)*(1 - g)*(1 + g)*(1 + h)*(1 + r), (1/4)*(1 - h)*(1 + 
      h)*(1 - g)*(1 + r), (1/4)*(1 - r)*(1 + r)*(1 - g)*(1 - h), (1/
      4)*(1 - r)*(1 + r)*(1 + g)*(1 - h), (1/4)*(1 - r)*(1 + r)*(1 + 
      g)*(1 + h), (1/4)*(1 - r)*(1 + r)*(1 - g)*(1 + h)};

cartCoords = NshapeList.gloCoordsEl;


spatialSMstep = 0.1;
spatialSmNat = 
  Flatten[Table[{xi, eta, zeta}, {xi, -1, 1, spatialSMstep}, {eta, -1,
      1, spatialSMstep}, {zeta, -1, 1, spatialSMstep}], 2];
nsG = Length[spatialSmNat];
nneis = 5;


neis = Array[0 &, {nsG, nneis}];
Do[asmPoint = spatialSmNat[[isG]];
 distances = Array[0 &, 27];
 Do[distances[[iG]] = {iG, 
    EuclideanDistance[asmPoint, xis[[iG]]]}, {iG, 1, 27}];
 neis[[isG, 1 ;; nneis]] = 
  Sort[distances, #1[[2]] < #2[[2]] &][[1 ;; nneis]], {isG, 1, nsG}]


spatialSmCart = 
  Table[cartCoords /. {g -> spatialSmNat[[j, 1]], 
     h -> spatialSmNat[[j, 2]], r -> spatialSmNat[[j, 3]]}, {j, 1, 
    Length[spatialSmNat]}];


svarG = {-9505.71, -8662.19, -8014.13, -9500.6, -8657.08, -8009.02, \
-9505.71, -8662.19, -8014.13, 2.*10^-8, 2.*10^-8, 2.*10^-8, 0., 0., 
   0., -2.*10^-8, -2.*10^-8, -2.*10^-8, 9505.71, 8662.19, 8014.13, 
   9500.6, 8657.08, 8009.02, 9505.71, 8662.19, 8014.13};


svarsG = Array[0 &, nsG];
Do[svarsG[[isG]] = 
    Sum[svarG[[neis[[isG, in, 1]]]]/(0.001 + neis[[isG, in, 2]]), {in,
        1, nneis}]/
     Sum[1/(0.001 + neis[[isG, in, 2]]), {in, 1, nneis}];, {isG, 1, 
   nsG}];
```

Here is the definition of List1

```
spatialXYZFsm = Append[Transpose[spatialSmCart], svarsG] // Transpose;
list1 = spatialXYZFsm;

spatialTestSm = 
  Flatten[Table[{x, y, z}, {x, 2.5, 5, 0.125}, {y, 0, 1, 0.05}, {z, 0,
      1, 0.05}], 2];
```

Here is the definition of List2

```
spatialXYZDummySM = 
  Table[Join[spatialTestSm[[i]], {svarsG[[i]]}], {i, 1, 
    Length[spatialTestSm]}];
list2 = spatialXYZDummySM;
```

Here is the proof, that both lists are equal

```
booList = 
  Table[spatialXYZDummySM[[i, j]] == spatialXYZFsm[[i, j]], {i, 1, 
    Length[spatialXYZFsm]}, {j, 1, Length[spatialXYZFsm[[1]]]}];
Select[Flatten[booList], Not[True[#]] &];
```

Here is the call to ListSliceContourPlot

```
ListSliceContourPlot3D[list1]
ListSliceContourPlot3D[list2]
```

Does anyone have an Idea why ListSliceContourPlot3D plots List2 perfectly but only an empty box when evaluating List1?

Thanks :)

Comment: It looks like several definitions are missing from your code - please make sure that your code works as expected when run on a fresh kernel (i.e. go to Evaluation>Quit Kernel>Local and then evaluate the code from the question, without anything else). Some of the missing things are `svarsG` and `spatialSmNat`

Comment: thanks @LukasLang :). I fixed it as you indicated... can you execute it now?

Comment: For me, both plots are empty - also, `xis` is still undefined

Comment: thanks again...i've added the definition of xis... anything now?

Comment: Hm... This is indeed strange. The lists are not exactly the same (`list1 === list2` returns `False`), but that doesn't really explain the failure to plot one of them.

Comment: i got it :) got the clue when you posted that the lists are not equal. Adjusting the precision of the elements of list1 with Round did it